# How to select HTML input elements, and change values, in Javascript to run an equation?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the input fields to change certain values of an equation in order to give a resultant angle. I have managed to select the default values and log the answer to the console however when i try to change the values nothing changes?

My end goal is to have an app where you can input these 3 values and hit "submit" and then it will output the answer on the screen. So for the default values it will output "The Angle is: 36.92°"

```js
const height = document.getElementById("height").value;
const trussSpan = document.getElementById("trussSpan").value;
const rafter = document.getElementById("rafter").value;
const hypot = Math.hypot(height, (trussSpan / 2));
const t1 = Math.atan2(height, (trussSpan / 2)) * 180 / Math.PI;
const t2 = Math.atan2(rafter, hypot) * 180 / Math.PI;
const result = Number((t1 - t2)).toFixed(2);

console.log("height: " + height);
console.log("Truss Span: " + trussSpan);
console.log("Rafter Depth: " + rafter);
console.log("Hyptonuse: " + hypot);
console.log("Angle 1: " + t1);
console.log("Angle 2: " + t2);
console.log("The angle of the truss is: " + result + "°");
```

```css
div{
    text-align: center;
    color: maroon;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}
    
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: maroon;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Angle Finder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angleFinder.css">
</head>

<body>
    

      <div>
            <label for="height">Height: </label>
            <input type="number" id="height" value="2000">

            <label for="trussSpan">Span: </label>
            <input type="number" id="trussSpan" value="5000">

            <label for="rafter">Rafter Depth: </label>
            <input type="number" id="rafter" value="97">
            <br>

            <input type="submit" id="submit">
       </div>

        
    <h1> Angle Finder</h1>


    <script src="angleFinder.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes:
Firstly, add a `<h2 id="theResult"></h1>` after the Angle Finder where you will display the result.

Secondly, put the code of the js file inside of a function called `getResult()`.

Thirdly, in the html file, call the `getResult()` function as the onclick event of the input. The "onclick" attribute in the "input" tag links your button to the javascript function so that it will be called whenever the button is clicked.

`<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="getResult()">`

Lastly, add `document.getElementById("theAnswer").innerHTML = result;` to the end of the `getResult()` function so that it will update the innerHTML of the `<h2 id="theAnswer">` tag.

---

See below changes:

#### html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Angle Finder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angleFinder.css">
</head>

<body>
    

      <div>
            <label for="height">Height: </label>
            <input type="number" id="height" value="2000">

            <label for="trussSpan">Span: </label>
            <input type="number" id="trussSpan" value="5000">

            <label for="rafter">Rafter Depth: </label>
            <input type="number" id="rafter" value="97">
            <br>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="getResult()">
       </div>

        
    <h1> Angle Finder</h1>
    <h2 id="theResult"></h1>

    <script src="angleFinder.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

#### JavaScript file:

```
function getResult() {
    const height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    const trussSpan = document.getElementById("trussSpan").value;
    const rafter = document.getElementById("rafter").value;
    const hypot = Math.hypot(height, (trussSpan / 2));
    const t1 = Math.atan2(height, (trussSpan / 2)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    const t2 = Math.atan2(rafter, hypot) * 180 / Math.PI;
    const result = Number((t1 - t2)).toFixed(2);

    console.log("height: " + height);
    console.log("Truss Span: " + trussSpan);
    console.log("Rafter Depth: " + rafter);
    console.log("Hyptonuse: " + hypot);
    console.log("Angle 1: " + t1);
    console.log("Angle 2: " + t2);
    console.log("The angle of the truss is: " + result + "°");

    document.getElementById("theResult").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this so quickly. That's exactly what I am looking for.